# Go: Funcs and Structs

Tags: go

I have a generated sqlc functions and structs here

```
const getAccount = `-- name: GetAccount :one
SELECT id, owner, balance, currency, created_at FROM accounts
WHERE id = $1 LIMIT 1
`

func (q *Queries) GetAccount(ctx context.Context, id int64) (Account, error) {
    row := q.queryRow(ctx, q.getAccountStmt, getAccount, id)
    var i Account
    err := row.Scan(
        &i.ID,
        &i.Owner,
        &i.Balance,
        &i.Currency,
        &i.CreatedAt,
    )
    return i, err
}

func (q *Queries) queryRow(ctx context.Context, stmt *sql.Stmt, query string, args ...interface{}) *sql.Row {
switch {
case stmt != nil && q.tx != nil:
    return q.tx.StmtContext(ctx, stmt).QueryRowContext(ctx, args...)
case stmt != nil:
    return stmt.QueryRowContext(ctx, args...)
default:
    return q.db.QueryRowContext(ctx, query, args...)
}
}
```

I am in process of learning Golang and need some clarification of what is happening in the code.

From my understanding, GetAccount takes 2 parameters ctx and id which returns either a Account Model or error model

In this function, variable row is assigned and automatically inferred to q.queryRow and passes in ctx, q.getAccountStmt, the sql query and id.

So what is q.getAccountStmt?

And What is func (q *Queries) mean here?

Also why is err assigned to row.Scan()?

when it states return i, err; does it mean it will return both i and err?

Comment: We'd need to see how Queries is defined. Is your code from https://docs.sqlc.dev/en/stable/howto/select.html

Comment: Yes, I'm confused with the syntax func (q *Queries) mean. I"m coming from javascript background.

Answer (score 4):

> What is func (q *Queries) mean here?

It means the function is a method to be called on a pointer to a Queries type. That pointer is put into the variable `q`. `q` is like `this` in Javascript, but you get to choose the variable name. See [Go By Example: Methods](https://gobyexample.com/methods) and [Effective Go: Methods](https://golang.google.cn/doc/effective_go#methods).

> What is q.getAccountStmt?

This gets the value stored in the field `getAccountStmt` from `q`, which we know from above is a pointer to a Queries struct. See [Go By Example: Structs](https://gobyexample.com/structs).

> Why is err assigned to row.Scan()?

The other way around, the return value of `row.Scan()` is assigned to `err`. `row.Scan()` returns an error code, this is how Go generally handles errors. See [Go By Example: Errors](https://gobyexample.com/errors) and [Effective Go: Errors](https://golang.google.cn/doc/effective_go#errors).

`row.Scan()` only returns an error because it puts the values read from the database row directly into its arguments. That is why they are passed as pointers. See [Go By Example: Pointers](https://gobyexample.com/pointers).